# Need explanation for `~0` vs. `2**64` with and without `use integer`

Tags: perl, numbers, output

I wrote some test program printing the values of `~0` and `2**64`:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
#use integer;
print ~0, "\n";
print 2**64, "\n";
```

Without `use integer` the program outputs

```text
118446744073709551615
1.184467440737096e+19
```

With `use integer` the program outputs:

```text
-1
1.184467440737096e+19
```

The other odd thing is that even when using `print int(2**64)` the number is output in scientific format still, just as if `int(...)` wasn't there (Still `~0` without `use integer` is output in "integer format").

I can force integer output using `printf("%u\n", ...)`, however.

(Perl being used in 5.18.2 of SLES12 SP5 on x86_64)

### Questions:

So why is `2**64` a "float" with and without `use integer`, while `~0` never is?

And with `use integer` when `~0` is print as `-1`, it still satisfies the condition `~0 > 2**63` (when I'd expect `-1` *not* to be greater than any positive value (like `2**63`).

### Update

There seems to be another odd effect seen in the Perl debugger:
`2^64` is an odd integer, and `2^64-1` is `-2`.

```perl
  DB<22> if (1) { use integer; print 2**64, "\n" }
1.84467440737096e+19

  DB<23> if (1) { use integer; print 2**64 - 1, "\n" }
-2
  DB<13> if (1) { use integer; printf '%x', 2**64-1, "\n" }
fffffffffffffffe
  DB<14> if (1) { use integer; printf '%x', 2**64, "\n" }
ffffffffffffffff
  DB<15> if (1) { no integer; printf '%x', 2**64, "\n" }
ffffffffffffffff
  DB<16> if (1) { no integer; printf '%x', 2**63, "\n" }
8000000000000000
```

Comment: `x**y` is generally calculated internally as `exp(y*log(x))`

Comment: @mob OK, but why isn't `int(2**64)` an integer as `~0` is?

Comment: It is an integer, it's just expressed in scientific notation.

Comment: 2**64 is a 65-bit integer. But `print int(2**63)`  produces an integer.

Comment: If you want `2**64` to be represented as an integer (on either 32-bit or 64-bit perl), then look into [`bigint`](https://metacpan.org/pod/bigint).

Comment: Re "*but why isn't int(2**64) an integer as ~0 is?*",  `int` returns an integer, but it might not be stored internally as an IV or UV. That's because it works on any number. For example, `int(2**99)` is perfectly valid, returning `2**99`. This is outside the range of your IV and UV types. On the other hand, the bitwise operators only work on native integer types.

Comment: @mob So it seems the ting that I missed is that `118446744073709551615` is `2**64 - 1`, while `1.184467440737096e+19` (even if looking to be identical) actually is `2**64`. Is that the ture reason for the effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *So why is `2**64` a "float" with and without `use integer`*

Exponentiation is calculated using floating point numbers and thus produces a float. I don't know why `use integer` doesn't force the result to be cast to a signed integer, but it doesn't. This is consistent with its documentation, which states that the pragma only affects the operands and results of:

- the arithmetic operators (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `%`, `+=`, `-=`, `*=`, `/=`, `%=`, and unary minus)
- the comparison operators (`<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`, `==`, `!=`, `<=>`), and
- the bitwise operators (`|`, `&`, `^`, `<<`, `>>`, `|=`, `&=`, `^=`, `<<=`, `>>=`)

In fact, it specifically excludes `**`.

> The power operator `**` is also not affected, so that 2 ** .5 is always the square root of 2.

---

> *while `~0` never is?*

The machine only has operations for performing bitwise operations on integer types, and they return integer types. There's no point in converting the number to a float (and plenty of reasons not to on a build with 64-bit ints).

> And with `use integer` when `~0` is print as `-1`, it still satisfies the condition `~0 > 2**63` (when I'd expect `-1` *not* to be greater than any positive value (like `2**63`).

`use integer` causes many operators to cast values to IV, and `<` is such an operator. Casting `2**63` produces -9223372036854775808 on my machine.

```
$ perl -M5.010 -Minteger -e'say 0 + 2**63'
-9223372036854775808
```

Comment: When trying it, I get the same result, but I don't understand the magic of `0 +`: If I leave it out, then I get `9.22337203685478e+18`. So does `use integer` actually apply to the `+` and not to `**`?

Comment: Asked another way: So does `use integer` have no effect for the `**` operator (and thus to its result)? As I understand it `0 +` does the magic, as `use integer` modifies `+` to make the result integer. If that's true, maybe add that to the answer.

Comment: Worded question more clearly, and adjusted answer for this new reading.

Answer (score 1):

Manual page `perlop(1)` explains in section "**Integer Arithmetic**" that `use integer` will cause a signed interpretation of integer results, so that will explain `118446744073709551615` vs. `-1`.

The other thing is that with 64-bit integers `2**64` actually is a *65*-bit number than cannot be presented as integer.
So that's interpreted as floating-point number.

And maybe, most important:
`~0` is **not** `2**64`, but `2**64 - 1`.

One only effect I cannot explain is why `int floor(2**64 - 1)` isn't output as integer number like `~0` or `0xffffffffffffffff` are.

Comment: The missing bit of information can be found in https://stackoverflow.com/a/68897554/6607497